# Creating dynamic icons based on data entered into database from django forms

Tags: mysql, django

So I'm using Django to create a projects page with multiple forms for each project. Let's call them form 1, 2, 3, and 4. Once you create a project you can fill out any of these forms. I want to create "buttons" or links for each one of the forms that would show up on the main page. Now this is the part I need help with:

Step 1. I want it so that if you click on a button for a form (say form 1) and none exists for that project yet a pop up would come up saying "This form does not exist yet, are you sure you want to create one?". And if you'd answer yes you would be directed to the form page.

Step 2. But if that form does exist, I don't want any pop up to open and I want the link to take the user directly to that page.

Step 3. My next problem is this. These forms are in order, so if you didn't create form 1 but created form 2, I don't want to give the user access to form 1. So in this scenario, if you click on form 1 I want a pop up to open and say "This form can no longer be created", and the link wouldn't function anymore.

Basically the button will have 3 function. First it should look at the database and if data for that specific form exists it should do "Step 2", if data for that form and the proceeding forms don't exist it should do "Step 1", and if data for that form doesn't exist but data for proceeding form's does exist is should do "Step 3".

Is this possible? Please help as I need to find a solution to this soon. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: What do you have so far, and how doesn't it work?

Comment: There's a lot going on in this question.  What you might want to do is focus on just a small section, work on it, then ask questions about just that section.